# How to put R code into a parameter of a newcommand?

Tags: macros, r, code

I would like to put R code into a parameter of a newcommand in LaTeX. To do it, I make the following:

```
%Define the newcommand:
\newcommand\solution[1]{\sf #1}

%Then, after the \begin{document}, I write:

\solution{
<<echo=T>>=
x=rnorm(100)
@
}
```

in my `.Rnw` file.
After I do R CMD Sweave file.Rnw, all is OK but when I do
`pdflatex file.tex`, the response is:

```
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `> x=rnorm(100) \end {Sinput} \end {Schunk} ' between \begin
{Sinput}[<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}

l.12 }
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Can you say more about what you're trying to accomplish?  Sweave inserts its own LaTeX environment, so it's not surprising at all that just wrapping the results in `\sf` would fail.  It will probably be easier to debug by working on the LaTeX file produced by Sweave ...

Comment: Here it is the LaTeX file produced by Sweave: \documentclass{article}
%Define the newcommand:
\newcommand\solution[1]{\sf #1}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}

%Then, after the \begin{document}, I write:

\solution{
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> x=rnorm(100)
\end{Sinput}
\end{Schunk}
}


\end{document}

Answer (score 1):

The chunks are `verbatim` like structures, thus cannot be used inside `\macro{....}`, make a `solution` environment instead (BTW use `\sfseries`, not `\sf`)

You might get away with just

```
\newenvironment{solution}{\sffamily}{}

\begin{solution}
<<echo=T>>=
x=rnorm(100)
@
\end{solution}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. In fact, what I want to do is a little bit more complicated: I want to create a "solution" environment for my exams but I want to control when the solutions appears. To do it, I do the following:

Comment: See the comment package, it can switch environments on and off. Or use environ package to make an envelope that some times eats up its contents without typesetting it